# How can I split name in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a column in my table with 1000 names. I want to make a new column by splitting the name in new format: Example:

```
Santosh Kumar Yadav
```

It should be:

```
Santosh K Yadav
```

Middle name with only initials and rest name should be the same.

How can I do it ?

Comment: at first try something to learn & share your code with problem details

Comment: How do you plan to handle someone whose name has 4 or 5 parts (and I have seen such Indian names before)?

Comment: Tag the dbms used, many of them have their own string handling functions - so the answer may be product specific!

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is replace second name with Initial. Here's an idea for MySQL database.

Assuming the name of names column is `name` & new column where you want to put data is `formatted_name`. You could try this.

```
UPDATE Users 
SET formatted_name = REPLACE(
                             name,
                             SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1), 
                             LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1), 1)
                             );
```

Here's the demo
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e5f95

Answer (score 0):

Following solution in Java

```
// get name from database and store in var1

String[] nameType = var1.split (' '); 
// divide var1 into firstname middlename lastname by splitting name with 'space'

var1 = nameType [0] + ' ' + nameType [1].substring (0, 1) + ' ' + nameType [2]; 
// combine name types, but only first letter of middle name

// write var1 in database
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make use of the below code. Its working fine in SQL Server 2012.

**Note** : This will work only for name with 3 parts.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Name Varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @Table
(Name)
VALUES
('Santhosh Kumar Yadav'),
('John Thomas Mathew'),
('Thomas Mathew John'),
('Mathew John Thomas'),
('John Mathew Thomas')
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(Name,1,CHARINDEX(' ',Name)+1) + 
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Name),1,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(Name)))) AS Name
FROM 
    @Table
```

Comment: awesome..., tnxxxxxxxxxxxx.

Answer (score 0):

The OP didn't mention the db vendor. The sample version for Oracle:

```
with mynames (name) as 
(select 'Santosh Kumar Yadav'  from dual
 union all
 select 'Abc Defgh' from dual)
      select  
       case when length(name) - length(replace(name, ' ', '')) + 1 < 3 then 
        name
       else 
      regexp_replace(name,'(^| )([^ ])([^ ])*',' \2',2, 1) 
      end 
     from mynames
```

It replaces only second word in the string when string has more than 2 words.

Answer (score 0):

For this result like

> 'Santosh Kumar Yadav' into 'Santosh K Yadav'

. You should create a function that convert

> from 'Santosh Kumar Yadav' into 'Santosh K Yadav'

```
create function FullNameToShort(@name varchar(100))
returns varchar(100)
begin
    declare @input varchar(100)
    set @input=@name
    declare @i int
    declare @output varchar(100)
    declare @ch varchar
    declare @lname varchar(25)
    declare @flag int
    set @flag=0
    set @i=1
    while @i<=LEN(@input)
     begin     
        if(SUBSTRING(@input,@i,1)=' ')
         begin
          set @lname=(SUBSTRING(@input,@i,len(@input)-@i+1))
          select @ch=(SUBSTRING(@input,@i+1,1))
          if(@flag=0)
           begin 
            select @output=(SUBSTRING(@input,0,@i))        
            set @flag=1      
           end 
          set @output=@output+' '+@ch       
         end                               
        set @i=@i+1
     end 
     select @output=SUBSTRING(@output,0,LEN(@output))
    set @output= @output+@lname
    return @output
end

select dbo.FullNameToShort('Santosh Kumar Yadav')
```

Its convert the all middle name into one char

Comment: `insert into tabName (name) select dbo.FullNameToShort(name) from table1`

use this function to insert data from one table to anothers

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
select substring('Santosh Kumar Yadav',1,charindex(' ','Santosh Kumar Yadav')+1) + reverse(substring(reverse('Santosh Kumar Yadav'),1,charindex(' ',reverse('Santosh Kumar Yadav'))))
```

Comment: That is an example string. He doesn't want to change just 'Santhos kumar Yadav`.

Comment: I just tell him the logic which is 100% correct.. I don't have his table structure...

Comment: That means he has to manually type each & every user's name, right? I'm sure that is not what he is looking forward for.